# Using Easy_Install with pypy on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to execute the following code

```
pypy easy_install [something]
```

I encounter

> no such file or directory: 'easy_install'

How do i make `pypy` work with easy_install?

I know there are some similar questions but i need a windows solution and i didn't understand the linux explanation.

These are my system and application specifications

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7 32-bit ([source](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/))
- pypy 2.6.0 ([source](http://pypy.org/download.html))
- setuptools 18.1(ez_setup) ([source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools))

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but if `pypy` is anything like standard python, you will have to run scripts/modules by using the `-m` flag:

```
pypy -m easy_install pkg
```

Python's help entry states:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

Comment: This actually worked! i assume -m tells to pypy to search a python 2.7 module? anyway thank you very much!

Comment: I think ``-m`` tells it to search the ``python/scripts/`` directory.  I could be wrong though.  in any case I'm glad my answer helped.  Please select it as the answer ;)